# richfaces exception at rendering picklist

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, jboss5.x

I am working on a project in which I use RichFaces JSF implementation.

I use Jboss 5.1 application server  and RichFaces 3.3.

The application works fine with RichFaces, untill I want to use a pickList component.

I get the following:

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)...
```

rootcause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.richfaces.renderkit.ConvertedSelectItem.get(ConvertedSelectItem.java:43)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.PickListRenderer.getConvertedItems(PickListRenderer.java:523)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PickListRendererGen.doEncodeChildren(PickListRendererGen.java:283)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PickListRendererGen.doEncodeChildren(PickListRendererGen.java:264)
    org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
```

Can anyone help me?

(Let me know if other details are needed)

Comment: I guess there are problems with items list. Are you sure you provide correct list of items? How do you use the picklist on your JSF page?

Comment: on my colleagues stations the page is properly displayed. It worked at some moment even on my station, but I don't know what hapened that I get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
richfaces exception at rendering picklist

Add this code in your picklist.xhtml page

<h:panelGroup>
    <rich:pickList id="rightsList" listsHeight="92px;" 
    tabindex="7" sourceListWidth="340px;"
    value="#{userManagementForm.rightsPickList}"
    targetListWidth="340px;" showButtonsLabel="true"
    style="float:left;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{rightsList}" />
    </rich:pickList>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Do you possess some magic crystal ball that lets you see what the OP needs for markup? And can you, for the less initiated of us, explain why this fixes the OP's error?